# React datepicker from npm package in a modal doesn't match the css with bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, datepicker, modal-dialog

React datepicker from npm doesn't match the css in a modal with bootstrap

I use bootstrap example in my project. For some components I use npm package such as select, datepicker...
With select (there is no css in addition) is everything ok, but datepicker is a little messy with css.
I would like date be like the other elements. Any suggestions please???

```
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import '../../css/bootstrapUnminified.min.css'
import '../../css/paperkitUnminified.css'

<DatePicker
  placeholderText={'Date'}
  dateFormat={"dd/MM/yyyy"}
  todayButton={"Today"}
  selected={dateSelected}
  onChange={this.dateChange}
 />
```